# How to make text in Blogger non-clickable?

Tags: blogger, blogger-themes

I have recently started using **Blogger** to write blogs.

I wanted to make my text non clickable in Blogger so nobody can copy that material from my blog.

I add the material using a **Compose button**. Its more or less similar to writing in Microsoft Word. Blogger automatically generate HTML code of it.

*I think that their should be a script that i should insert in the html code that will make my code non clickable.* But I don't know much about html. What should i do to achieve this task?

[image: enter data just like in word]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used this code to disable the right mouse click & text non-highlightable.

In Blogger Go to Layout>>> Add a Gadget >> Select HTML/JavaScriptAdd

Then paste a code in it.

```
<script language='JavaScript'>
function disableselect(e){
return false
}
function reEnable(){
return true
}
document.onselectstart=new Function ("return false")
if (window.sidebar){
document.onmousedown=disableselect
document.onclick=reEnable
}

<!--

//Disable right mouse click Script
//Disable right click script Mix By Divyang Patel Notice: Don't Remove the Credit 
///// 
var message="Function Disabled!";

///////////////////////////////////
function clickIE4(){
if (event.button==2){
alert(message);
return false;
}
}

function clickNS4(e){
if (document.layers||document.getElementById&&!document.all){
if (e.which==2||e.which==3){
alert(message);
return false;
}
}
}
//Disable right click script Mix By Divyang Patel Notice: Don't Remove the Credit 
if (document.layers){
document.captureEvents(Event.MOUSEDOWN);
document.onmousedown=clickNS4;
}
else if (document.all&&!document.getElementById){
document.onmousedown=clickIE4;
}

document.oncontextmenu=new Function("alert(message);return false")
</script>
<!--Code End Mix By Divyang Patel>
```

But This create some problems in the page like disable some gadgets that run on java script.

Comment: You do realize that all this will do in most cases is annoy people who might have a legitimate want to select or copy the text? It's otherwise academic to "view source" or turn off JavaScript and get the content that way.

Comment: Yup. Right.  Does their is anothe way other than JavaScript . that is fool proof?

Comment: Not and also have the content online and presentable by a browser.

Answer (score 0):

This is not something which Blogger automatically supports.

But you can add CSS   (Template > Customize > Advanced > CSS)    which will do this, and then apply the relevant style in the post-editor's Edit HTML mode.

See this question for information about the CSS to use:    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/826782/how-to-disable-text-selection-highlighting-using-css